# Issue with opening local web page from other local one on Xamarin.UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.uwp

In Xamarin.Forms project I've got help which is local web pages. Online one is not an option as the product I'm working will be used in locations without Internet connection. The web page is loaded using Xamarin's WebView. Here is the code sample.

```
var files = DependencyService.Get<IFiles>();
var webView = new WebView();
webView.Source = Path.Combine(files.GetBaseUrl(), "HelpFolder", "index.htm");
Content = helpHTMLView; //Assigning to page content
```

GetBaseUrl() iOS

```
    public string GetBaseUrl() => NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
```

GetBaseUrl() Android

```
    public string GetBaseUrl() => "file:///android_asset/";
```

GetBaseUrl() UWP

```
    public string GetBaseUrl() => "ms-appx-web:///";
```

The help on Xamarin Android and iOS version is loading properly (HTMLs, CSSs and JavaScript). When I'm clicking on the link on a page on the both platforms the next local webpage is loaded.

However on Xamarin.UWP I can't open local web pages from local one's link using the same code. I can open first web page with some problems. However when I click a link on the page I've got the message below.

[image: Error when opening link the page]

What do I have to configure to allow loading other local web page? Xamarin's documentation is suggesting to load file but it seems too awkward. Using the sample from the documentation loads only HTML without CSS and scripts. The ideal solution would be to just give an address to local path and a page would open.

Comment: Have you followed the link below? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#universal-windows-platform What issue did you get? Could you provide more details for us to reproduce?

Comment: I've been on the page. I've got platform dependent base uri and web pages in the platform dependent project. However I don't utilize HtmlWebViewSource. I assign path (base uri + folder + main page) to WebView.SourceProperty using binding to a property. It works on Android and iOS devices. For the problem reproduction create linked webpages with scripts, CSS and save in some folder in platform dependent project.Then try to access it from application.

Answer (score 0):

> However I don't utilize HtmlWebViewSource. I assign path (base uri + folder + main page) to WebView.SourceProperty using binding to a property.

The WebView's Source property could be set with a string URL to display a website from the internet. Please note, the URLs must be fully formed with the protocol specified (i.e. it must have "http://" or "https://" prepended to it).

Follow the MS docs to use the `HtmlWebViewSource` to set the `BaseUrl` property. The docs put the html file in the project root with the build action set to Content.

If you want to put the file in the folder of Xamarin.UWP project, you could change the `BaseUrl` as `ms-appx-web:///html///`. The `html` is the name of the folder.

**Load Html CS code:**

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public interface IBaseUrl { string Get(); }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var browser = new WebView();
        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

        //htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
        //                    <head>
        //                    <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""default.css"">
        //                    </head>
        //                    <body>
        //                    <h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1>
        //                    <p>The CSS and image are loaded from local files!</p>
        //                    <img src='XamarinLogo.png'/>
        //                    <p><a href=""local1.html"">next page</a></p>
        //                    </body>
        //                    </html>";

        htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get() + "local1.html";//local1 is the html file in html folder

        browser.Source = htmlSource;
        Content = browser;
    }
}
```

**BaseUrl:**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl))]
namespace App16.UWP
{ 
    public class BaseUrl : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return "ms-appx-web:///html///";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution. I used htmlwebviewsource and loaded HTML from file utilizing BaseURL. However, it only loads HTML without CSS and JavaScript which is much worse compared to loading problem next local page. The CSS and JavaScript are in sub-folder of main page.

Comment: Do not only give me the decription. Could you provide the a code snippet for what you want?